# Showing two given rings are isomorphic

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ring-homomorphism

Let $K$ be a field and $R=K[x,y]$ be a polynomial ring in the variable $x$ and $y$. let $R_1=R[y/x]$ is a subring of the quotient field of $R$. Let $R_2=R[t]/(xt-y)$. show that $R_1$ and $R_2$ are isomorphic.
The problem that I can show that there exists a homomorphism from $R[t]$ to $R_1$ by sending $t$ to $y/x$. But I am unable to show that the kernel of this homorphism is indeed equal to $(xt-y)$. Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That $(xt-y)$ is inside the kernel is clear. For the reverse inclusion, take $p(x,y,t)$ such that $p(x,y,y/x)=0$. Divide $p$ by $-y+xt$ to get $p(x,y,t)=q(x,y,t)(-y+xt)+r(x,t)$. Compute the image of this by your map. The left side goes to zero and so does $q(x,y,t)(-y+xt)$ due to the factor $-y+xt$. The right hand side will go to $r(x,t)$. Therefore, $r(x,t)=0$.

Comment: I just have one question. So we are showing the image of r(x, t) under this mapping is 0. How can if be shown that r(x, t) is identically equal to 0

Comment: The image is $r(x,y/x)$. You can look at it as a polynomial in $y$ and go coefficient by coefficient, from lowest degree to higher. The degree zero part is the same as that of $r(x,t)$, as a polynomial in $t$. So, that is zero. Factor out $y/x$ from $r(x,y/x)$ and $t$ from $r(x,t)$ and repeat.

Answer (score -1):

Let us denote your map by $\phi$. We can prove this by showing two inclusions: $(xt-y) \subseteq \text{Ker}(\phi)$ and $\text{Ker}(\phi) \subseteq (xt-y)$. I think the first one you can look at yourself.

For the second one, take an arbitrary $f \in R[t]$ such that $f \in \text{Ker}(\phi)$.
Then $f(y/x) = 0$. This means that $f(t) = 0 \bmod (xt-y)$, therefore $f(t)$ can be factored as $(xt-y) \cdot g(t)$, for some $g \in R[t]$. Hence $f \in (xt-y)$.

Comment: Why was this downvoted, but not the comment giving (in my eyes) the same answer? When I started writing this answer the comment didn't exist yet. I'm just curious, no hard feelings

Comment: Maybe because the claim that $f(y/x)=0$ means that $f(t)=0\mod{(xt-y)}$ is pretty much what needs to be proven. $f(y/x)=0$ is what we know, and $f(t)=0\mod{(xt-y)}$ is the same as $f(t)\in(xt-y)$.

Comment: Dividing by (xt-y) and then showing that the remainder is 0 is the same as my mod claim. But I can see that your comment makes this more explicit and is therefore more complete.

Comment: Dividing by $xt-y$ and showing that the remainder is $0$ is a proof of that claim, not the same as the claim itself. The conclusion $f(t)=0\mod{(xt-y)}$ is the definition of $f(t)\in(xt-y)$. So, the claim is not showing anything, only restating what is asked. It is like saying "it is true because it is true".